# Unable to re-assign JavaScript variables with new Razor data?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a partial view which has some js function's which contain Razor code which I assign to some js variables . for the first time js is rendered with correct data later on if I **make a other partial call** the js data **doesn't change** .

**_Pview.cshtml:**

```
@model Myproject.Models.Sample
<script>
  var sample = '@model.test';
</script>
```

**Code:**

```
public ActionResult RequestDataSource()
{
 //model mapping goes here (I use request.query string to fetch different data)
 return PartialView("_Pview", model);
}
```

**Note:** I'm trying to load model with different razor data. I'm trying to re-use partial view but JavaScript once assigned doesn't seem to change .

Comment: Scripts should not be in partials. What are you trying to do with this?

Comment: Can you show where you call the controller Pview?

Comment: I assume you mean a modal (dialog) not model? But that is no reason to put a script in a partial. The script in the main view can handle the events of any element in that partial

Comment: Your going to need to edit your question with a bit more detail to explain what you trying to do.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i made my question more constructive & precise . can you have look at it . cheers